# How to save data in iOS app

Tags: ios, save

I am developing an iOS application which generate random inspirational quote every day.
At the moment when I close the app, open it again and click on the button which generates the daily quote, it shows me a new one.

Can you help me, how can I save the same quote all over the day and when the day is over generate a new one.

I want to keep 1 quote per day, not 1 quote for every time I open the app.

Comment: Google `NSUserDefaults` and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by saving the quote and the time it was generated in `NSUserDefaults` (in Swift3, this will be called `UserDefaults`

First, generate your quote, and store it as a String in a variable. We'll call this `myQuote`. Next, get the current time by initializing a new `NSDate` object (as of Swift 3, `Date`), and getting the time interval since 1970, (`.timeIntervalSince1970` in Swift) and store it in a variable, which we will call `myTime`.

Then, when the user opens the app, get the stored time, and check if it is over a day old. If it is, then generate a new quote and store it. If it isn't, just display the stored quote.

Here's an example of how to to this using **Swift 2**

```
// get the quote stored in NSUserDefaults for the key "storedQuote"
let storedQuote: String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("storedQuote")
// get the time stored in NSUserDefaults for the key "storedTime"
let storedTime: Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("storedTime")

// get the current time interval since 1970
let currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let quoteToDisplay: String

// if the stored quote doesn't exist, or it has been more than 
// a day (60 * 60 * 24 seconds) since the quote was stored
if(storedQuote == nil || currentTime - storedTime >= (60 * 60 * 24)){
    // generate a new quote
    quoteToDisplay = myFunctionForGeneratingANewQuote()

    // store the newly generated quote for the key "storedQuote"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(quoteToDisplay, forKey: "storedQuote")
    // store the current time for the key "storedTime"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentTime, forKey: "storedTime")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
else{
    // otherwise, the quote != nil and was generated less than a day ago
    // so this one should be displayed
    quoteToDisplay = storedQuote!
}

//display quoteToDisplay
myFunctionForDisplayingAQuote(storedQuote)
```

In Swift 3, all instances of `NSUserDefaults` and `NSDate` will be replaced with their new names, `UserDefaults` and `Date` respectively.

Whenever you want to display the quote, you should call the code above. In your case, this will most likely be your `viewDidLoad` function

Comment: Thank you very much.
Would you provide me with a sample example of the code. I am new to Swift and it is a bit difficult for me.
At the moment I am reading the quotes from a json file, if that helps you

Comment: No problem! I did provide you with an example of the code - just replace `myFunctionForGeneratingANewQuote()` with your function for... well, generating a new quote, and `myFunctionForDisplayingAQuote(storedQuote)` with the way you would display the quote `storedQuote`. Make sure to also read the comments, so you actually *understand* what the code is doing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are awesome! Would you check my code?

Comment: @IvanSosev You should be putting the code wherever you usually put the code to display your quote (so probably `viewDidLoad`)

Comment: @IvanSosev It looks like it's in the right place - try running it and see what happens

Comment: I can't understand only where is the function for: myFunctionForDisplayingAQuote(storedQuote)
I do not see it anywhere and I think that is the problem

Comment: @IvanSosev the code youshowed looked right for that - it doesn't have to be a function, only whatever code you use to display the quote (in your case setting the text of a label)

Comment: Hey can you please check it on your mac I get something wrong:(  I appreciate it very much!! It is very important for me!
http://biobeehive.com/code2/

Comment: @IvanSosev It doesn't look like you're generating a new quote, calling the display method, or setting the text correctly. The line `quoteToDisplay = String (Label1.text)` should be changed to `quoteToDisplay = ivan()`. And, instead of displaying the quote in `ivan()`, you should be returning the quote. Instead of setting the text of the label at the end of the `RandomWord()` function to `storedQuote`, it should be set to `quoteToDisplay`. Lastly, you need to call the `RandomWord` function when the user launches the app, so in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I get 3 errors and 1 of them is quoteToDisplay = ivan() , it says that can't assign value to string()
Please show me the correct code, it is really important for me :(

Comment: @IvanSosev If you're getting an error on that line, it's because you aren't returning the String in `ivan()` - read my last comment about making it return a String instead of setting the label. Everywhere in the `ivan()` function where you set the text of the label, return the text instead

Comment: You mean this: quoteToDisplay = ivan(storedQuote)

Comment: @IvanSosev Try [clicking on this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120271/chat-between-jojodmo-and-ivan-sosev). It should bring you to a chat room where I can help you more.

Comment: it says you must have reputation 20 :(
Do you have skype or maybe in teamviewer

Comment: @IvanSosev It shows that you're in the room. Are you sure that you can't chat? I made you an owner of the room so you should be able to

Comment: in the text field I get this message:
You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: can we try in different site please :(

Comment: @IvanSosev Alright, here's a link: http://us21.chatzy.com/64752089710556... The website is a little odd, but It'll work

Comment: do you get my messages?

Comment: @IvanSosev Yes, I responded too

Comment: I changed the code please check it here:
http://biobeehive.com/code-3/
I changed the seconds to 1, so that I do not have to wait 24hours. 
But it seems that nothing is changed I get only 1 Quote. Please check it, it doesn't show another quote after the second.

Comment: hey are you online?

Comment: hey are you there? I did it.

Comment: yes thank you verymuch, But I have another problem. Do you know how can I take the names and the coordinates of the places from my json file and populate them into an array which I am going to use for displaying a list ( Table View Cells)

Comment: @IvanSosev By that do you mean looping through all of the values in the JSON file?

Comment: @IvanSosev Yea, sure! What you need is to turn the JSON string into an `NSDictionary?` using `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary`. Then, once you have your dictionary and have unwrapped it, you can get an Array `[AnyObject]` of all of the keys using `dictionary.allKeys`